# How can I create a stored procedure to only allow inserts in a particular month?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g, sql-insert

I want to create a stored procedure that only does inserts in the month of March. The stored procedure should accept values for the table but use the system date to determine if the records should be inserted.

This is what I was trying but procedure created with errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_time_1203383 (
   p_sales_id IN sales_1203383.SALES_ID%TYPE,
   p_product  IN sales_1203383.PRODUCT%TYPE,
   p_unitcost IN sales_1203383.UNITCOST%TYPE,
   p_quantity IN sales_1203383.QUANTITY%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
    IF( MONTH( GETDATE() ) = 3 )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO sales_1203383 ("SALES_ID", "PRODUCT", "UNITCOST", "QUANTITY") 
        VALUES (p_sales_id, p_product,p_unitcost, p_quantity);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Can Only insert during the month of March'
    END

    COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also why not just test `IF( MONTH( GETDATE() ) = 3 )`

Comment: I am using oracle 11g command line and it says procedure created with compilation errors

Comment: I tried with your suggestion..same error @Dai

Comment: Please post the **exact** error message you're getting from the database system, including any error codes, line numbers or character offsets.

Comment: A request for a procedure that only inserts in a certain month, using sysdate; a table with an appended number on it. This smells bad. Perhaps you could explain the bigger picture.

Comment: ok so I already have a table called sales_1203383 so I'm trying to create a SP to only insert if in month of march. Created the sp with the sql code given and it says "warning procedure created with compilation errors". When I try to execute it with "exec sp_time_1203383(12, 'bag' , 40.0, 6);" it says error ORA-06550: object StudentA_1203383.sp_time_1203383 is invalid". line 1 column 7

Comment: Should n't this be `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_....... (...) AS` instead of **IS**

Comment: [They're synonyms](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373) @Kumar.

Comment: Why is this table named this way? Is it only allowed to contain data for march? Have you heard of a partitioned table? I suggest you look it up because it seems that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think Praveen gave you the right advice.

I personally would not use the

```
SELECT count(1) into v_cnt FROM dual WHERE month(sysdate) = 3;
```

but you can check in a if ... then ... else ... end; statement with the following code:

```
if to_char(sysdate,'mm') = '03' then ... end;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your stored procedure:

1. You cannot have `select` with `if` statement
2. Use `then` with `IF` statement and at end `End if`
3. `;` has to be used with `End` statement
4. You cannot return a `select set` from a `procedure/function/block` (ref cursor should be used)
5. If you want raise error in the `else` part use `raise_application_error`.
6. If your select statement is like `select 'something'` use dummy table `dual`, `select 'something' from dual`

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_time_1203383 (
   p_sales_id IN sales_1203383.SALES_ID%TYPE,
   p_product  IN sales_1203383.PRODUCT%TYPE,
   p_unitcost IN sales_1203383.UNITCOST%TYPE,
   p_quantity IN sales_1203383.QUANTITY%TYPE
) 
IS
    v_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(1) into v_cnt FROM dual WHERE month(sysdate) = 3;
    IF v_cnt > 0 THEN 
        INSERT INTO sales_1203383 ("SALES_ID", "PRODUCT", "UNITCOST", "QUANTITY") 
        VALUES (p_sales_id, p_product, p_unitcost, p_quantity);
    ELSE
        raise_application_error(-20101, 'Can Only insert during the month of March');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP asked for, you don't need to be counting. If the sysdate is in March then allow the insert, otherwise raise the error.